# Can't authenticate google app to read email

Tags: google-api, gmail, google-oauth, google-apps

Need to give possibility for script to read my gmail account.

There is a VM in google cloud with api. If api is called, the script goes to gmail, gets mails and processes them, returning result as api response.

I run api, and when I'm making request to this api from localhost, there is a message in api logs: Please visit this URL to authorise this application:

```
https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth?response_type=...
```

After opening this URL in web browser I get 400 error:

```
Error: redirect_uri_mismatch

The redirect URI in the request, http://localhost:34067/, does not match the ones authorized for the OAuth client. To update the authorized redirect URIs, visit: https://console.developers.google.com/apis/credentials/...
```

I have created OAuth 2.0 Client ID, downloaded client_secret.json file and put it on my server. I thyed different redirect urls in OAuth 2.0 Client ID settings, but nothing helped.

How to avoid 400 error on visiting google oauth url?

Comment: have you tried adding the redirect URI to the project on Google developer console?

Comment: Yes. This didn't help.